# Reactjs setState() does not immediately mutate this.state, How should I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set a state in my code, but since setState() does not immediately mutate this.state I'm trying to do it in a call back. But can't figure out the correct syntax for it. Below is the code. After user press a button the `update()` method is called. There are these two states: `this.state.tmp` and `this.state.rec`. `this.state.rec` is a MAP, and it's a copy of `this.props.rec`. I need to compare the new value of `this.state.rec` and `this.props.rec` (calling it `patch`) and run a api call.

`this.state.rec` should have the changes so: on line #2, first I create `rec`. it gets the new value from `this.state.tmp` and then I need to update `this.state.rec` with  this new value. But obviously the `updated` is not getting the value the way it is now. Can someone please tell me how to fix it?

```
update(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    const rec = this.state.rec.set('something', this.state.tmp);
    let updated = this.setState({rec}, () => {
            return this.state.rec.toJS();
    });
    console.log("updated = ", updated)
    const original = this.props.rec.get('data').toJS();
    const patch = compare(original, updated);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Why you can't use `componentDidUpdate` and inside it call your "patch" code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setState(updater[, callback])`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) accepts a `callback function` as a second param, however, performing comparison of `next` and / or `previous` `state` within [`componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) or [`componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) appears to be more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: thanks, I moved the code to componentDidUpdate() and it works

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
    this.setState(function(state, props) {
    //You can write your logic here to decide to
    //make api call or not.
    return {
    newValue : state.newValue + 1,
    newAttribute: state.newAttribute - 1,
    newValueFromProps: props.newValue,
    }
})
```

Please let me know it that worked for you

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used `componentDidUpdate()` and it works now. Also tried your suggestion but it didn't work. Or maybe I made a mistake because it's not clear to me how to use your code.